# handling error in async waterfall with expressjs

Tags: node.js, error-handling, express, waterfall, node-async

I don't see why expressjs don't handle error when it's throw in async.waterfall

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express.createServer()
, async = require('async');

app.use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
}));

app.get('/error', function(req, res){
    throw Error('Aie');
});

app.get('/asyncerror', function(req, res){
    var that = this;
    async.waterfall([
        function(next){
            console.log('1');
            next("42", "2");
        },
        function(arg, next) {
            console.log(arg);
            res.json('ok');
        }
        ], function(err){
            console.log(this);
            throw Error('Aie');
        });
});

app.listen(8888, function(){
    console.log('Listen on 0.0.0.0:8888');
});
```

When i GET /error , expressjs print a nice error without crash serveur but when i GET /asyncerror it's a classic throw, print on stdout with server crash ..

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Express never has the opportunity to catch the exception that's thrown in the `/asyncerror` example as you're throwing it from within an `async` callback context and not an Express middleware context.  In general, if you don't want an error condition in an async function to crash your node app, report the error via the callback instead of throwing it.  In this case you can call the `next` parameter that your `app.get` callback is receiving but you're not using.  Try this instead:

```
app.get('/asyncerror', function(req, res, next){
    var that = this;
    async.waterfall([
        function(next){
            console.log('1');
            next("42", "2");
        },
        function(arg, next) {
            console.log(arg);
            res.json('ok');
            next();
        }
        ], function(err){
            console.log(this);
            next(Error('Aie'));
        });
});
```